# Show the solution of this problem is an Affine Set

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have a matrix $A$ and let us denote $a_i^T$ denote the $i$ th row.
Consider the problem:

$$Ax < b \in \mathbb R^n, \quad \quad \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{b_i-a_i^Tx} =0, \quad x\in \mathbb R^m$$

How to show if there are multiple solutions i.e multiple $x$'s solving the aforementioned problem then it forms an affine set? Also how to show this will have an unique solution if and only if $\{x|Ax<b\}$ is nonempty and bounded?

Comment: Multiple solutions of what? That is a nice little summation you have there, but unless you say something about that summation, there is nothing to "solve".

Comment: @PaulSinclair shit..my bad ....I completely missed it thanks.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I didn't understand your reasoning quite. But the idea here is that this is a polygon defined by hyperplanes which are defined by the rows of A. If it is unbounded it means that the polygon extends infinitely else it is bounded like a triangle, parallelogram etc.

Comment: Nevermind. I was too strongly influenced by the case where the image (or column) space of $A$ is $\Bbb R^n$. If it is lower dimensional, then the set will be bounded unless the image of $A$ is parallel to a coordinate hyperplane.